# What am I getting wrong about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration

Reputable sites say the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus relates the integral of a *continuous* function f(x) to f's antiderivative F, such that $I\equiv\int_{a}^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$, and that $I$ represents the area under f between a and b.

I could imagine distorting f by adding a bump somewhere between a and b, while keeping it continuous and also leaving f unchanged around a and b.  This would also keep F(a) and F(b), and therefore I unchanged.  However, the area would clearly have changed.

What am I getting wrong?  Does "f is continuous" mean to all orders of its derivatives?  (The same reputable site seems to say only continuity in f itself is required.)

Comment: If you add a bump somewhere in the integral, then the value of $F(b)$ will increase

Comment: You are wrong in thinking that make a "local" change to $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$ ("bump") will not change $F(x)$ at $x=a,b$.  While one of those $F(a),F(b)$ could be left fixed (because the antiderivatives are a family  of functions with the "+C" term), they will not both stayed fixed unless the bump is rather special.

Comment: If you change $f$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ will change.

Comment: The function $F(x)$, if it's differentiable, has only **one** derivative; its derivative may be $f(x)$, or $f(x)$ with the bump, or neither, **but not both**. So the original $f(x)$ and your $f(x)$ with the bump, can't both have the same function $F(x)$ as an antiderivative.